# R: ggplot incompatibility between shape and fill aesthetics at plot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot using fill and shape aesthetics. The plot looks wonderful however the legend does not get colored by the fill aesthetics. Could you please help me to sort this out?

Here an example code

```
#Example dataset
bio_rep = rep(c(1:3), 4)
category = rep(c("w", "x", "y", "z"), each = 3)
ranking = sample(c("s","a","b","c"), 12, replace = T)
score = runif(12)

df = data.frame(bio_rep, category, ranking, score)

> df
   bio_rep category ranking      score
1        1        w       b 0.12496463
2        2        w       b 0.82229942
3        3        w       b 0.20121351
4        1        x       a 0.06352934
5        2        x       s 0.57510752
6        3        x       a 0.54471793
7        1        y       a 0.87203684
8        2        y       c 0.32858945
9        3        y       a 0.06234144
10       1        z       c 0.41124401
11       2        z       s 0.62253128
12       3        z       a 0.42499771
```

Now the plot

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(category, score, shape = factor(bio_rep), fill = ranking))+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,22,23))
```

As you can see, **ranking** does not get colored in the legend

[Image link here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8h0l.jpg)

Do you know how to solve it?

Many thanks in advance
MP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the default shape used by the "ranking" legend does not have a `fill` aesthetic (only `color`). You can change this shape to match the ones in your other legend using `override.aes`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(category, score, shape = factor(bio_rep), fill = ranking))+
    geom_point(size = 3)+
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,22,23)) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend( override.aes = list(shape=21) ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thar was an amazingly fast answer :O Many thanks for your help Artem! :)